# Wifi Connection Instability

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, mesh-networking

Recently, I've had some incredibly bad luck with wifi in my small NYC apartment and have tried a number of things to debug/troubleshoot, but have been unable to find a solid root cause, so I'm turning here to get some new ideas!

I was recently running an AmplifiHD mesh kit (router + 2 mesh points) in my apartment with a single SSID that supported both 2.4GHz and 5GHz devices with band steering on (meaning devices that could use 5GHz would be 'steered' to connecting to that frequency). However starting early last week I kept getting "incorrect password" prompts on my MacBook Pro when trying to connect to this network. I though it could be the beta software I was testing, so I also tried on my stock Pixel 3 device that I used for testing and it was experiencing the same issues.

I tried re-configuring the network locations on the mac, as well as forgetting all networks on both the laptop and the phone, but nothing seemed to solve this issue. I ended up factory resetting the router just in case, and at that point the mesh points also stopped connecting to it! At this point I was out of ideas, and I turned on the "make 5GHz SSID" option just to see if that worked, and everything connected!

I figured something was going on with this router based on the mesh points, so I dusted off my old AirPort Extreme to isolate that bad hardware. I setup the AirPort Extreme in a similar way (main network was mixed 2.4 and 5GHz, and a 5GHz specific SSID) and experienced the same issue. I could connect to the 5GHz network, but not the main network across multiple devices.

At this point, I'm not sure what's going on as this issue happening across multiple routers, multiple end devices, multiple resets etc. I have a Unifi Dream Machine coming soon so I can get better introspection from the router's perspective of things. Noise and signal levels seem normal (meaning the main network and the 5GHz network have the same noise and signal levels which makes sense since they are in a single unit).

So I'm looking for advice on other things I should be looking for to try to debug this situation as it feels like maybe I'm just missing something I'm not considering.

Comment: My first thought was that someone else in or around you is broadcasting the same SSID as you, either maliciously or accidentally, and you were getting incorrect password errors because of that. However, it could be that the mesh points are somehow out of sync with the main router and don't have their passwords set properly. Have you tried a full reset on all the mesh points and router, and then resetting the entire system?

Comment: What is the noise floor in your environment? How much above the noise floor is your signal? I'm curious, I live in the suburbs and the 2.4 band is a mess, so I always figured it would be worse somewhere like nyc. I agree with Sam, this sounds like someone around you is deauthing your devices, maybe the evil twin attack. If you have the option in your router, and support with your devices you could try management frame encryption.

Comment: Hey Sam, yeah I’ve tried resetting the mesh points and then the router a few time now without any luck unfortunately. The weird thing is about a potential malicious attacker, even when I set the network to have no password I’ll get an incorrect password message. Tim, any more info you could share on detecting and mitigating the evil twin attack? There is certainly a lot of networks around me (not familiar how to measure the noise floor though), but things had been fine for just about a year until this point which is weird.